# Set a TCP port > 65535 with pcap and dnet

Tags: sockets, tcp, wireshark, packet, pcap

I have been injecting packets on the network and watching the effects via wireshark. I am able to correctly set and change tcp ports and set the source and destination. However, I am now having an issue. One of the things I need to do is to set a source port from port 66,000. Every time I try it just puts the number to 1163 in wireshark which is because it is supposed to be a short integer. Does anyone know how to make it accept the big number. I know the big endian and htonl should work so I tried that as well but that didn't solve the issue.

Here is the code I am using

```
void extract(u_char *user, struct pcap_pkthdr *h, u_char *pack ) {
  struct eth_hdr *ethhdr;
  struct ip_hdr *iphdr;
  struct tcp_hdr *tcphdr;

  ethhdr = (struct eth_hdr *)pack;
  iphdr = (struct ip_hdr *)(pack + ETH_HDR_LEN);
  tcphdr = (struct tcp_hdr *) (pack + ETH_HDR_LEN + (4*iphdr->ip_hl));
  //Set the ports
  tcphdr->th_sport = htons(66666);
  tcphdr->th_dport = htons(atoi(destString));
```

Comment: You don't 'have to do' this at all. You can't. There is no such thing as TCP port 66,000, or any value that doesn't fit into 16 bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The port number is 16 bit. With 16 bit you can get only up to 65535. No way around it. See also the TCP header at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure.